# GoogleMap Using Modal Overlay instead of InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, overlay, infowindow

I want to use a Custom Info Window. that has no arrow no shadow, a `panTo`. custom CSS rules. right now I am using `Overlay` they are being shown properly. but as they should act like an `InfoWindow`. they should be closed `onBlur` But overlays don't emit any such event. Should I hook for `onclick` event on `map` ? or there is an even better solution. how `InfoWindow` work ? Do `InfoWindow` Hooks for `click` event from `map` ?